# WhereExpression method not found in SubSonic 3.0.0.4?

Tags: subsonic3, constraints, sql

This is my first ever post on any forum, so excuse my etiquette.

Im using SubSonic 3.0.0.4 and was trying to concat a Fluent Query using ActiveRecord, I want to be able to use the WhereExpression method of SqlQuery to start adding a list of 'OR' statements with brackets round, to exclude the list from other constraints E.g.

```
var qry =
db.Select.From<DocumentHeader>();

qry.WhereExpression(DocumentHeadersTable.InvoiceNoColumn).Like(myList.Items[0]);

for (Int32 i = 1, n = myList.Items.Count; i < n; i++) {
    qry.Or(DocumentHeadersTable.InvoiceNoColumn).Like(myList.Items[i]);
}

qry.CloseExpression();
```

There is more to it than this but this is a rough example. Searching on the web and looking at the Fluent Query page of SubSonic it suggests that the method WhereExpression does exist, but looking at the Intellisense and then in the source code downloaded from the GitHub, I could only find a Property not a Method. I have managed to do a workaround for the above problem, but the WhereExpression would be useful.

So after all that my question is, has this method been removed? or its usage changed? Or most likely Im being stupid and looking in the wrong place?

Thanks in advance.
Lee

Comment: Thanks dusan for the edit :) when hacking at my older code to get an example I took more off than I meant lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the WhereExpression got another implementation due to a massive addition of LINQ support in the version 3.0, so just use the `Where` method instead.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it might have changed, but the documentation on the original web site still uses it in an example. So its good to know Its good to know I'm not going completely mad :) Thanks again. (I would give +1 but I dont have the rep yet)